# Any likely causes of a double-free in ncurses?

Tags: c++, c, ncurses

I have an ncurses app that does the following, sometimes instantly after launch, sometimes after some fiddling.

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x100300400: double free
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted
(gdb) where
#0 0x00007fff846a7426 in read ()
#1 0x00007fff83f3d775 in _nc_wgetch ()
#2 0x00007fff83f3de3f in wgetch ()
(and so on into my code)
```

Does anyone have suggestions for likely things to pursue?

Comment: Code is simply a wgetch(stdscr) call.  Looking more for reasons why wgetch might abort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using glibc, likely on an x86_64 Linux system.

*The* tool to use for any kind of heap corruption on Linux/x86_64 is [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). It will just immediately give you the answer, so there is no point in guessing where the problem might be (and it could be *anywhere*).

Comment: glibc, Darwin, 10.6 so valgrind is out of the question.  Then again, I also have Ubuntu, putting valgrind back on the table.  Thanks.